# My Spring application throwing Whitelabel Error page instead of working with binding results

Tags: java, spring, validation, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am trying to configure validation in my practical training. But instead of showing me the error message in the page, so that user cannot send empty or too large text, its sending me to the Whitelabel Error page with the error that my message didnt go through validation.

1. .pom depencies

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

2. Message class

```
package com.example.springmvcapp.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "message_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "message_seq", sequenceName = "message_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please fill the message")
    @Length(max = 2048, message = "Message too long (more then 2kB)")
    private String text;
    private String tag;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;

    private String filename;
    public String getAuthorName(){
        return author != null ? author.getUsername() : "<none>";
     }
}
```

3. Main controller

```
package com.example.springmvcapp.controller;

import com.example.springmvcapp.domain.Message;
import com.example.springmvcapp.domain.User;
import com.example.springmvcapp.repos.MessageRepo;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.thymeleaf.util.StringUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    private final MessageRepo messageRepo;

    public MainController(MessageRepo messageRepo) {
        this.messageRepo = messageRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        return "greeting";
    }

    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(
            @RequestParam(name = "filterValue", required = false) String filterValue,
            Model model
    ){
        Iterable<Message> messages;
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(filterValue)){
            messages = messageRepo.findByTag(filterValue);
        } else {
            messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        }

        model.addAttribute("filterValue", filterValue);
        model.addAttribute("message", new Message());
        model.addAttribute("messages", messages);
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/index")
    public String messageSubmit(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            @ModelAttribute @Valid  Message message,
            @RequestParam(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file ,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model
    ) throws IOException {

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);
            model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap);

            //return "index"
        } else{
            if(file != null && !file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()){
                File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);

                if(!uploadDir.exists()){
                    uploadDir.mkdir();
                }
                String uuidFile = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                String resultFileName = uuidFile + "." + file.getOriginalFilename();
                file.transferTo(new File(uploadPath + "/" + resultFileName));
                message.setFilename(resultFileName);
            }

            message.setAuthor(user);
            messageRepo.save(message);
        }

        return "redirect:/index";
    }
}
```

4. The method that is used in "if" with bindingResult

```
package com.example.springmvcapp.controller;

import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ControllerUtils {

    static Map<String, String> getErrors(BindingResult bindingResult) {
        Collector<FieldError, ?, Map<String, String>> collector = Collectors.toMap(
                fieldError -> fieldError.getField() + "Error",
                FieldError::getDefaultMessage
        );
        Map<String, String> errorsMap = bindingResult.getFieldErrors().stream().collect(collector);
        return errorsMap;
    }
}
```

5. Thymeleaf template

```
<th:block th:replace="~{parts/common :: topBody}"/>


<form th:method="get" th:action="@{/index}" class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" name="filterValue" th:value="${filterValue}" placeholder="Search by tag" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>

<p class="d-inline-flex gap-1 mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseAdd" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseAdd">
        Add new message
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseAdd">
        <form th:action="@{/index}" th:object="${message}" th:method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <label class="visually-hidden" for="Text">Text</label>
                <div class="input-group-text">Text:</div>
                <input type="text" th:class="form-control" th:classappend=" ${textError ?: '.is-invalid'} "
                       th:value="${message.text}"
                       id="Text" th:field="*{text}" placeholder="Lets imagine something...">
                <div th:if="${textError}" class="invalid-feedback" th:text="${textError}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <label class="visually-hidden" for="Tag">Tag</label>
                <div class="input-group-text">Tag:</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tag" th:field="*{tag}" placeholder="Tag">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="File" class="visually-hidden">Choose file:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="File">
            </div>
            <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" value="Reset"/></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</p>

<div th:if="${messages.isEmpty()}">
    <p>No messages available.</p>
</div>

<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div th:each="message: ${messages}" class="card p-0 m-2" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div th:if="${message.filename != null}">
            <img th:src="@{/img/} + ${message.filename}" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${message.tag}"></h5>
            <p class="card-text" th:text="${message.text}"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <p class="card-text" th:text="${message.author?.getUsername() ?: '<none>'}"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<th:block th:replace="~{parts/common :: bottomBody}"/>
```

5. Error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 14 17:04:21 EEST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='message'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [1] in public java.lang.String com.example.springmvcapp.controller.MainController.messageSubmit(com.example.springmvcapp.domain.User,com.example.springmvcapp.domain.Message,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.IOException: [Field error in object 'message' on field 'text': rejected value []; codes [NotBlank.message.text,NotBlank.text,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [message.text,text]; arguments []; default message [text]]; default message [Please fill the message]] 
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Ive tried to add `server.error.include-binding-errors=always` into application.properties, tried to change the thymeleaf code to do something with that, logic of the controller

Comment: The `BindingResult` must directly follow the `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameter, yours isn't. Also fix your dependencies as you defined versions for some, don't let the `spring-boot-starter-parent` manage the versions.

Comment: Idk how i missed that it should follow it. I appreciate your help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) commented

> The BindingResult must directly follow the @ModelAttribute annotated parameter, yours isn't.

The problem was because of my BindingResult wasnt following Message that it was validating. Huge love!

*also thx for the dependencies tip*